# src.visualization is not defined as module

Tags: python, windows, jupyter-notebook

I have a problem with importing visualization module to Jupyter notebook on Windows 11.

Here's the code

```
from src.visualization import visualize
```

Here is the result

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 1
----> 1 from src.visualization import visualize
      2 """
      3 !pip install visualize
      4 """

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src.visualization'
```

This should be imported as a part of visualizing PPG data.

Comment: What is `src` in `src.visualization` ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have confirmed that pip is installed, you can proceed to install the visualize package.
You can run the following command to check it

> pip install visualize

If you use another "Python environment", You can install using this command,

> You can use the pip package manager to install it. In a Jupyter notebook cell or in the command prompt, run **!pip install visualize** to install the module

you have an active internet connection.

IF not fixed Error please ask.

Comment: Hi. I've install visualize. It seems the module is different from the src one. It gets the error.

AttributeError: module 'visualize' has no attribute 'create_dataframe'